# Combinatorial Proof of Multinomial Theorem - Without Induction or Binomial Theorem

Tags: combinatorics, alternative-proof, combinatorial-proofs

I've been trying to [rout out](https://www.google.com/search?q=multinomial+theorem+combinatorial+proof&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3afr%3aofficial&ei=6A2HUoH3EpKeiQe364CAAw&start=100&sa=N&biw=1366&bih=638) an exclusively combinatorial proof of the Multinomial Theorem with bounteous details but only lighted upon [this one - see P2](http://www.math.ust.hk/~mabfchen/Math232/Binomial-Coefficients.pdf.). Any other helpful ones?

> $(x_1+\cdots+x_k)^n =$ [Top of Page 39 from UNC](http://www.unc.edu/~vkulkarn/STOR215/alltext.pdf):
>   $\sum\limits_{\large{(a_1, ..., a_{k - 1}) \; \ni \; 0 \le a_1+...+ a_{k - 1} \le n}}\dbinom{n}{a_1,...,a_{k-1}}\cdot x_1^{a_1} \cdots x_{k-1}^{a_{k-1}}x_k^{\large{n - a_1 - \cdots - a_{k-1}}}$
>   $= \sum\limits_{\large{a_1+...+a_k = n \; \& \; a_i \ge 0 }}\dbinom{n}{a_1,...,a_k} x_1^{a_1} \cdots x_k^{a_k}$ [Bottom of P1 from MSU](http://www.math.msu.edu/~dhand/MTH481FS08/Notes7.pdf).

I see that both are the Multinomial Theorem but which one is better?

I thought to try this myself, following the combinatorial proof of the Binomial Theorem. So  esteem each term (in green) in $(x_1+\cdots+x_k)^n = \underbrace{\color{green}{[x_1+\cdots+x_k]...[x_1+\cdots+x_k]}}_{\text{n terms}}$ as one box from which to choose $x_1, ..., x_k$.
Since each term/box (in green) contains $k$ terms, the total number of terms $ = k^n$.

First, consider $x_1$.
● For $x_1^n$, must have $a_ 1 = n\qquad \& \qquad a_2 = ... = a_k = 0$.
● For $x_1^{n - 1}$, must have $a_1 = n - 1 \qquad \& \qquad a_2 \text{ OR } ... \text{ OR } a_k = 1$
(the latter due to $a_1+...+a_k = n$ in definition from P1 of MSU)
...
● For $x_1^{1},$ must have $a_1 = 1 \qquad \& \qquad a_2 \text{ OR } ... \text{ OR } a_k = n - 1$
● For $x_1^{0},$ must have $a_1 = 0 \qquad \& \qquad a_2 \text{ OR } ... \text{ OR } a_k = n$

The above extends to and must hold for all $x_1, ..., x_k$.
How to translate all this into combinatorial notation? How to forge ahead and complete please?

Comment: Can you use "balls-in-boxes", a.k.a, Stars and Bars? Each term of the expansion will contain $n_1 x_1's; n_2 x_2's,...,n_k x_k's$ , and the sum $x_1+x_2+...+x_k=n$ = number of sums of $k$ non-negative integers that add to $n$. This number of sums given as Stars and Bars , or balls-in-boxes,is precisely the general multinomial coefficient.

Comment: The first version of the MT is stated wrongly: by convention in a multinomial (not binomial) coefficient, the sum of the bottom indices should _equal_ the top index

Comment: The question is not clear. For _which_ description of multinomial coefficients are you trying establish that they are coefficients in the multinomial formula?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: Thank you. First comment: So is the PDF wrong or did I copy it wrongly? Second comment: I was vacillating between the two; I don't know which one's easier to work with.

Comment: You copied right, but the UNC author uses an unconventional notation for multinomial coefficients, suppressing the final lower index. Since the sum of the lower indices is given by the upper index it is redundant (and always omitted for _binomial_ coefficients), but for multinomial coefficients I have always seen it included for symmetry reasons: the final lower index plays the same role as all the other lower indices.

Comment: Most of your links are broken. Please update your post. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one approach: When you expand $(x_1+x_2+....+x_k)^n$ , you will have a collection of terms $c_ix_1^{n_1}x_2^{n_2}......x_k^{n_k}$ for each "box"/factor $i$ in your green, so that $n_1+n_2+..+n_k=n$.

For  a  fixed given $k$-tuple $(n_1,..,n_k)$ , the assignment of the $n_1, ..., n_k$ can be chosen in:

$\dbinom {n}{n_1} \times \dbinom {n-n_1}{n_2} \times.....\dbinom{n-n_1-....-n_{k-1}}{n_k}$  ways. The $n_1$ balls can be chosen from the original $n$. After having used up $n_1$ balls, you only have $n-n_1$ balls left, which you can use to choose the $n_2$ balls for $x_2$, etc.. This expansion is precisely the multinomial coefficient: $$\dbinom {n}{n_1,n_2,....,n_k} $$

The above is true only for the given $k$-tuple $(n_1,..,n_k)$. Now, we do the sum over all $k$-ples  $(n_1, n_2,....,n_k)$ with  $n_1+n_2+...+n_k=n$

The reason why we sum over all $k$-ples is that, when we expand the product :

$$ (x_1+x_2+...+ x_k)^n= \underbrace{(x_1 + x_2+...+x_k) (x_1+x_2...+x_k)....(x_1+x_2+..+x_k)}_{n \text{ times }}$$

, you will ultimately multiply one element $x_{j1}$ from the first copy of $(x_1+x_2+..+x_k)$ with one element $x_{j2}$ in the second copy,... with an $x_{jk}$ from the $k$-th copy of $(x_1+...+x_k)$,
i.e., the product will have one element of each copy of the sum.

Notice some specific cases/examples, for $k=n=3$; I think this will be clearer than
a more formal argument:

$(\color{green}{x_1}+x_2+x_3)(x_1+x_2+x_3)(x_1+x_2+x_3)$ : We start with $\color{green}{x_1}$, multiply by some element $x_{j2}$ in the second parenthesis to get $x_1x_{j2}$, and then we multiply this $x_1x_{j2}$ by some element $x_{j3}$ in the third parenthesis (notice that we may have $x_{j2}=x_1, x_2$ or $x_3$). How many different monomials can we have? Well, each monomial will contain 3 terms, possibly repeated, so that the sum of the exponents of $x_1x_{j2}x_{j3}$ will add up to 3, e.g., we will have terms like $x_1x_1x_2=x_1^2x_2$, or $x_1^3$, or $x_1x_2x_3$, etc.

How many monomials of this sort can we have? Well, we can have as many as the number of all the 3-tuples (ie triples) of the exponents, $(n_1, n_2, n_3)$ chosen with ordering and with replacement, for the respective terms $x_1,x_2,x_3$, such that $n_1+n_2+n_3=3$ (because each monomial contains $k = 3$ terms).

Basically, we are summing over all strings $(x_1^{n_1}x_2^{n_2}...x_k^{n_k})$ , where all the exponents add-up to $n$; this amount of terms is equivalent to the number of solutions of the equation $x_1+ x_2+....+x_k =n$

Comment: Actually, let me reedit a bit, and please tell me if you disagree with something or íf you don't think is clear.

Comment: @LePressentiment: No problem.Re the sum $n_1+n_2+...$ When you expand the product $(x_1+x_2+...+x_k)^n=(x_1+x_2+...+x_k)(x_1+x_2..._x_k)....(x_1+x_2+..+x_k)$ (n times ) , you will ultimately multiply one element $x_i$ from the first copy of (x_1+x_2+..+x_k) with one element $x_{j2}$ in the second copy,... with an $x_{jk}$ from the $k-th$ copy of $(x_1+...+x_k)$, i.e., the product will have one element of each copy of the sum.

Comment: @LePressentiment: Basically, when we expand $(x_1+x_2+...+x_k)^{n}$ we are summing all strings of $n$ elements made of the elements {$x_1,x_2,..,x_k$}, with possible repetition of elements $x_i$ in the length-n strings. This means we have all strings (with possible repetition of x_i's) of the type $x_1^{n_1}x_2^{n_2}....$. If a given $x_i$ in $x_1,x_2,..,x_j$ does not appear in the product, then $n_i=0$. The number of terms is then the total number of sums of exponents $n_1,n_2,..,n_k$ with $n_1+n_2+...+n_k=n$.

Comment: @LePressentiment: Please see also my edit above, and let me know if you have a follow-up.

Comment: Upvoted. Thank you very much! I made some incidental edits for latex and formatting. Please let me cogitate over this for a few days and I'll get back to you. In the meantime, could you please move your previous comments into your answer? I forgot to request whether you could lodge all content into your answer; subscripts in comments are harder to read.

Comment: @LePressentiment: Hi, sorry for the delay; I just wrote the comments that were not part of the post into the post.

Comment: No need for apologies! Thank you very much again. I'm the one to be sorry to preoccupy you. Another question: Could you please clarify *there are $\color{red}{\text{triples of exponents }} n_i,n_j,n_k$ for the respective terms $x_i,x_j,x_k$ with $n_1+n_2+n_3=3$*? In particular, I'm having trouble with the red. Would you please answer in your answer once again.

Comment: I also wish that I could upvote more than once for your superlative efforts and diligence in helping me. I'll do so for your other Q & As.

Comment: @LePressentiment. No problem; glad to help. I think the best thing to do is just expand the multinomial (x_1+x_2+x_3)^3 , and similar. Maybe you can use: http://www.wolframalpha.com/ to do these expansions. Basically, the monomials that result from the expansion will be triples ( k-ples in general ), and the exponents $n_1, n_2,..,n_k$ will just describe/reflect, how many copies of each $x_k$ you have in the triple ( k-ple) .

Comment: Thank you profoundly. I didn't register what had been meant by "there are $\color{red}{\text{triples of exponents }} n_i,n_j,n_k$," but I think I grasp it now so I just edited this part of your answer to enlarge on it. Is it right? Did I miss anything? Please feel free to edit my edit and to answer in your answer.

Comment: LePresentiment: The edit is right. Sometimes it takes a few weeks to absorb some things; hope this will happen soon, given your good determination and effort. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you profoundly. I think I grasp it now, centrally due to your continued care and dedication to my questions and supplementaries.

Answer (score 2):

The multinomial theorem says that for commuting quantities $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ in a ring one has
$$
  (X_1+\cdots+X_k)^n=\sum_{\substack{a_1,\ldots,a_k\in\Bbb N\\a_1+\cdots+a_k=n}}
  \binom n{a_1,\ldots,a_k}X_1^{a_1}\ldots X_k^{a_k}
$$
where the multinomial coefficient $\binom n{a_1,\ldots,a_k}$ can be defined (under the hypothesis $a_1+\cdots+a_k=n$, without which it is either left undefined, or maybe set to$~0$), either combinatorially as the number of words (of length$~n$) over the alphabet $\{A_1,\ldots,A_k\}$ containing $a_i$ copies of the letter$~A_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,k$, or algebraically as $\frac{n!}{a_1!\ldots a_k!}$.

A combinatorial proof of the multinomial theorem would naturally use the combinatorial description of multinomial coefficients. It is almost a triviality: without assuming that the $X_i$ commute, the $n$-th power can be expanded by the distributive laws to a sum of $k^n$ *distinct* monomials in the $X_i$, which are just all distinct words of length $n$ that can be formed from them; now assuming commutation, one groups together all words that have the same number of copies of each$~X_i$, and if those multiplicities are $a_1,\ldots,a_k$ respectively, then one gets $\binom n{a_1,\ldots,a_k}$ times the monomial $X_1^{a_1}\ldots X_k^{a_k}$.

The equivalence of the combinatorial and algebraic description of multinomial coefficients is another matter, but also quite simple. For a word of length$~n$ with given multiplicities $a_1,\ldots,a_k$ of individual letters, the $n!$ permutations of the letters of the word certainly generate all words that can be made from that multiset of letters, but each word is obtained multiple times. To obtain from one way to generate a word all other ways to generate the same word, one can independently permute all copies of a *same* letter among each other, which can be done in $a_1!\ldots a_k!$ ways. This means there are$\frac{n!}{a_1!\ldots a_k!}$ distinct words.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n$ be a positive integer. For all $x_1$, $x_2$,..., $x_k$, $$(x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_k)^n=\sum {n\choose n_1,n_2,...,n_k}x_1^{n_1}x_2^{n_2}\cdots x_k^{n_k},$$ where the summation extends over all non-negative integral solutions $n_1,n_2,...,n_k$ of $n_1+n_2+\cdots +n_k=n$.

Write $(x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_k)^n$ as the product of $n$ factors where each factor is $(x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_k)$. Using the distributive law we can expand this product and collect like terms. For each of the n factors we can choose one of the the $k$ numbers $x_1,x_2,...,x_k$ and form their product for $k^n$ terms. Each of these terms can be arranged in the form $x_1^{n_1}x_2^{n_2}\cdots x_k^{n_k}$, where the non-negative integer exponents $n_1,n_2,...,n_k$ sum to $n$ We obtain this by noticing that we can choose $x_1$ in $n_1$ ways of the $n$ factors, $x_2$ in $n_2$ ways of the remaining $n-n_1$ factors,..., $x_k$ in $n_k$ ways of the remaining $n-n_1-\cdots -n_k-1$ factors. Using the Multiplication Principle, we see that the number of times the term $x_1^{n_1}x_2^{n_2}\cdots x_k^{n_k}$ occurs is $${n\choose n_1}{n-n_1\choose n_2}\cdots {n-n_1-\cdots {n_{k-1}}\choose n_k}={n\choose n_1,n_2,...,n_k}.$$ Thus $$(x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_k)^n=\sum {n\choose n_1,n_2,...,n_k}x_1^{n_1}x_2^{n_2}\cdots x_k^{n_k}.$$

Comment: Thank you. Could you please enlarge on/elucidate the sentences starting from : *Using the distributive law we can expand this product ... We obtain $\color{red}{\text{this}}$"* ? For example, what does $\color{red}{\text{this}}$ refer to? What's an example of a *like term*? What's "their product for $k^n$ terms? Could you please explicate and reveal where $n_1+n_2+..+n_k=n$ comes from?

Comment: Also, will you please do so in your answer and not as a comment? Thank you!