# How to prove that $(3+2\sqrt{2})^n=a_n+b_n\sqrt{2}$ for some positive integers $a_n,b_n$ without induction?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I have to prove that without induction: Let $n$ is non-negative integer number, prove that:
$(3+2\sqrt{2})^n=a_n+b_n\sqrt{2}$ where $a_n, b_n$ are positive integer number

My try:
$a_1=3, b_1=2$

$a_{n+1}+b_{n+1}\sqrt{2}=(3+2\sqrt2)^{n+1}$

$a_{n+1}+b_{n+1}\sqrt{2}=(a_n+b_n\sqrt{2})(3+2\sqrt{2})$

$a_{n+1}=3a_n+4b_n$

$b_{n+1}=2a_n+3b_n$

Then I don't know how to prove that without induction. Thanks for help!

Comment: Recall Binomial theorem? Try combining even and odd terms. (of course, the proof of binomial theorem uses induction!)

Comment: $3+2\sqrt{2} = (1+\sqrt{2})^2$

Comment: As my professor would say: you cannot prove something like this without induction, you will always have implicit induction.

Comment: You can compute $(3+2\sqrt{2})^n$ for each value of $n$. That would prove it, for as many $n$'s you manage to compute, without induction.

Comment: $3+2\sqrt{2} = (1+\sqrt{2})^2$ so that,$(1+\sqrt{2})^{2n} = \sum^{i=2n}_{i=0} C^(2n)_{i} 1^{2n-i}(\sqrt{2})^(i)$, every term is of the form $l_n+\sqrt{2}m_n$ hence their sum is also of the form 
$a_n + b_n$

Comment: Note that same do not hold for $(1+ 2^{\frac{1}{4}})^n$. i.e. sum is not of the form $a_n + b_n 2^{\frac{1}{4}}$ but is $a_n + b_n 2^{\frac{1}{4}} + c_n\sqrt{2}$

Comment: @ABC I believe the idea is that induction is used when it comes to Peano's axioms. If you use a different axiomatic system for the natural numbers, induction will presumably also be involved.

Comment: Your statement is not true for $n=0$ because $b_0=0$, which is not positive.  But this is tiny point.

Answer (score 4):

$$\left(k+l\sqrt2\right)\left(m+n\sqrt2\right) = (km+2ln) + (kn+lm)\sqrt2$$

so terms of the form $a+b\sqrt2$ with $a,b$ positive integers are closed under multiplication and thus under positive integer powers.

Moving from multiplication to  positive integer powers may involve an implicit induction: I suspect that this is unavoidable if you want your statement to be true for all positive integer $n$.

Answer (score 2):

$$(3+2\sqrt{2})^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}3^{n-k}2^k(\sqrt2)^k=$$
$$=\sum_{j=0}^{n/2}\binom{n}{2j}3^{n-2j}2^{2j}(\sqrt2)^{2j}+\sum_{i=0}^{n/2}\binom{n}{2i+1}3^{n-2i-1}2^{2i+1}(\sqrt2)^{2i+1}=$$ 
$$=\sum_{i=0}^{n/2}\binom{n}{2i+1}3^{n-2i-1}2^{2i+1}2^i\sqrt2+\sum_{j=0}^{n/2}\binom{n}{2j}3^{n-2j}2^{2j}2^{j}=$$
$$=\sum_{j=0}^{n/2}\binom{n}{2j}3^{n-2j}2^{3j}+\sum_{i=0}^{n/2}\binom{n}{2i+1}3^{n-2i-1}2^{3i+1}\sqrt2$$
$$a_n=\sum_{j=0}^{n/2}\binom{n}{2j}3^{n-2j}2^{3j}$$
$$b_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n/2}\binom{n}{2i+1}3^{n-2i-1}2^{3i+1}$$

Comment: How do you prove the first equality?

Comment: That is binomial theorem.

Comment: Which requires induction.

Comment: Binomial theorem can be proven without induction

Comment: How would you do this?

Answer (score 0):

Let's prove the stronger claim that $a_n,b_n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ **and** ${a_n}^2 - 2{b_n}^2 = 1$. So $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\dfrac{a_n}{b_n}} = \sqrt{2}$ among other things.

---

Using the binomial theorem* you can establish that $(3 - 2\sqrt2)^n = a_n - b_n\sqrt2$ as $\sqrt2$ terms arise from odd powers of $(-2\sqrt2)$. These always have a negative sign.

> * Pertinent to the the binomial theorem:
>
> - The binomial theorem can be proved combinatorially. See [Combinatorial Proof of Multinomial Theorem - Without Induction or Binomial Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568973/combinatorial-proof-of-multinomial-theorem-without-induction-or-binomial-theor).
> - All powers of $3$ and all even powers of $2\sqrt2$ in expansions of both $(3+2\sqrt2)^n\text{ and }(3-2\sqrt2)^n$ are whole numbers. Likewise, odd powers of $2\sqrt2$ are whole multiples of $\sqrt2$.
> - For positive integer exponents, all binomial coefficients are whole numbers (combinatorial combinations)

Then you have (for some $a_n, b_n$ which are integers by the above):

$\begin{align}
(3+2\sqrt{2})^n&=a_n+b_n\sqrt{2} \\
(3-2\sqrt{2})^n&=a_n-b_n\sqrt{2}
\end{align}$

which solves to (including the case $n=1$)

$a_n = \dfrac{1}{2}[(3+2\sqrt2)^n+(3-2\sqrt2)^n] \tag{1}$

$b_n = \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt2}[(3+2\sqrt2)^n-(3-2\sqrt2)^n] \tag{2}$

Now $(3+2\sqrt2) > (3-2\sqrt2) > 0 \implies (3+2\sqrt2)^n > (3-2\sqrt2)^n > 0$, so both $a_n, b_n \ge 1$.

With these expressions for $a_n, b_n$, we can compute

$\begin{align}
{a_n}^2-2{b_n}^2 &= \dfrac{1}{4}[(3+2\sqrt2)^{2n}+2+(3-2\sqrt2)^{2n}] - 2\times\dfrac{1}{8}[(3+2\sqrt2)^{2n}-2+(3-2\sqrt2)^{2n}] \\
&= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}  \\
&= 1
\end{align}$

which is therefore an identity for all $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
\big( 2 \sqrt{2} + 3 \big) = \big(\sqrt{2} + 1\big)^2.
$$

First we construct a recursion relation by using
$$
\big( \sqrt{2} + 1 \big) \big( p_n \sqrt{2} + q_n \big) =
\big( \underbrace{p_n + q_n}_{\displaystyle p_{n+1}} \big) \sqrt{2}
+ \big(\underbrace{2 p + q }_{\displaystyle q_{n+1}} \big).
$$
Whence
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{rcl}
p_{n+1} &=& p_n + q_n\\
q_{n+1} &=& 2 p_n + q_n
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Therefore
$$
p_{n+2} = 2 p_{n+1} + p_{n}, \hspace{2em} q_{n} = p_{n+1} - p_{n}
$$
This is a *brother* of Fibonacci :)

We obtain the $\phi$ equation
$$
\phi^2 = 2 \phi + 1 \Rightarrow \phi_\pm = 1 \pm \sqrt{2}.
$$
And we obtain the solutions
$$
p_n = \frac{\phi_+^n - \phi_-^n}{\phi_+ - \phi_-}, \hspace{2em}
q_n = \frac{\phi_+^n + \phi_-^n}{\phi_+ - \phi_-} \sqrt{2}.
$$
So we obtain
$$
\big( \sqrt{2} + 1 \big)^n
= \frac{\big(1+\sqrt{2})^n - \big(1-\sqrt{2})^n}{2\sqrt{2}} \sqrt{2}
+ \frac{\big(1+\sqrt{2})^n + \big(1-\sqrt{2})^n}{2}.
$$

The final result is
$$
\big( 2 \sqrt{2} + 3 \big)^n
= \frac{\big(3+2\sqrt{2})^n - \big(3-2\sqrt{2})^n}{2\sqrt{2}} \sqrt{2}
+ \frac{\big(3+2\sqrt{2})^n + \big(3-2\sqrt{2})^n}{2}.
$$