# How to get to the powers

Tags: exponentiation

Consider: $(a + b + c + d)^{21}$

What will be the coefficient of $a^5b^6c^5d^5$?

Can you also give the general way of finding out coefficients of such terms?

Comment: Do you have only one sum to the power of some natural number ?

Comment: Since $5+6+5+5\neq 2$ the coefficient is zero.

Comment: @guestDiego You mean $5+6+5+5>2$.

Comment: @Peter - I have edited the question, had made a mistake.

Comment: Try for the coefficient of $a^5 b^6 c^5 d^5$ in $(a+b+c+d)^{21}$.

Comment: @Peter The coefficient would be zero also if $n_a+n_b+n_c+n_d=1$

Comment: 21- there you go

Comment: This is just a application of the multinomial theorem. I'm sure you could find an another question about this.

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

Comment: First of all, it should be clarified whether the question is about a single power.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568973/combinatorial-proof-of-multinomial-theorem-without-induction-or-binomial-theor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a^5b^6c^5d^5$ corresponds to the coefficient $$\frac{21!}{5!6!5!5!}$$ in the multinomial $(a+b+c+d)^{21}$. The corresponding value is $\color{red}{41\space 064\space 607\space 584}$.

Comment: So, does $a^7b^5c^8d^4$ in $(a + b + c + d)^{21}$ has a coefficient of __$\frac{21!}{7!5!8!4!}$__?

Comment: And I had another confusion: is it necessary that the powers of a, b, c and d must sum up to the x in **$(a + b + c + d)^x$**?

Comment: Always, like for Newton Binomial. You should get an homogeneous polynomial, so all the terms of the sum have same degree.

Comment: Respect to the coefficients, all the terms of the sum have the form $a^{n_1}b^{n_2}c^{n_3}d^{n_4}$ where $n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4=21$ (the same happens with the binomial).